# Why this insert query go into error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, database

I am very new to Microsoft SQL Server and I have a problem with this `INSERT` query that inserts a new record in a very very big table (it has many columns).

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument ([Id], 
                    [VulnerabilityAlertId], 
                    [SourceId], 
                    [BugTraqID], 
                    [Title], 
                    [StatusID], 
                    [CVE], 
                    [Published], 
                    [LastUpdated], 
                    [Remote],
                    [Local],
                    [Credibility],
                    [Classification],
                    [Availability], 
                    [Ease],
                    [Authentication], 
                    [CVSS2_BaseScore], 
                    [CVSS2_TemporalScore], 
                    [CVSS2_BaseVector], 
                    [CVSS2_TemporalVector], 
                    [CVSS1_BaseScore], 
                    [CVSS1_TemporalScore], 
                    [NVD_CVSS2_BaseScore], 
                    [NVD_CVSS2_ComponentString], 
                    [ImpactRating], 
                    [Severity], 
                    [EaseofExploit], 
                    [UrgencyRating], 
                    [LastChange], 
                    [ShortSummary], 
                    [Impact], 
                    [TechnicalDescription], 
                    [AttackScenario], 
                    [Exploit], 
                    [Credit], 
                    [URL], 
                    [AlertStatusId], 
                    [Type], 
                    [DetailLevel], 
                    [Language], 
                    [dd])
VALUES('10000', 
       '10000', 
       'TEST', 
       '5',
       'TEST TITLE',
       '1',
       'TEST CVE',
       '1998-04-30 00:00:00.000',
       '2007-11-05 16:32:34.000',
       'TEST REMOTE',
       'TEST LOCAL',
       'TEST CREDIBILITY',
       'TEST CLASSIFICATION',
       'TEST Availability',
       'TEST EASE',
       'TEST Authentication',
       'TEST CVSS2_BaseScore',
       'TEST VSS2_TemporalScore',
       'TEST CVSS2_BaseVector',
       'TEST VSS2_TemporalVector',
       'TEST CVSS1_BaseScore',
       'TEST CVSS1_TemporalScore',
       'TEST NVD_CVSS2_BaseScore',
       'TEST NVD_CVSS2_ComponentString',
       '2',
       '3',
       '10',
       '7',
       'TEST LastChange',
       'TEST ShortSummary',
       'TEST IMPACT',
       'TEST TechnicalDescription',
       'TEST AttackScenario',
       'TEST Exploit',
       'TEST Credit',
       'TEST URL',
       '5',
       '3',
       '1',
       'TEST Language',
       'NULL');
```

In which I insert a specific value into a specified column (I specify columns by the first query section, and I specify the related values by the second section of the query)

The problem is that when I try to execute the previous query I obtain the following error

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'VulnerabilityAlertDocument' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Why? What does this mean? How can I change my query to solve this problem and so insert the record in  my table?

Comment: The error is being thrown'VulnerabilityAlertDocument'  but its actually ID that needs to be removed from the INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SET IDENTITY_INSERT VulnerabilityAlertDocument ON` before `INSERT`

After `INSERT`, add `SET IDENTITY_INSERT VulnerabilityAlertDocument OFF`

Comment: mmm what do you exactly mean?

Comment: I have not the permission to do it

Answer (score 1):

you have an identity column then you don't have to insert the Id, you have to delete Id from your query and the value of the Id

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [Id] column from the list of columns and its corresponding value '10000'. The error is due you are trying to populate a column with a value and SQL is complaining that a automated handled value just he can provide.
BTW, you don't need to quote your numeric values if that columns are of numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` before your query.
Identity columns are auto-increasing and so do not allow insertion.
You need to explicitly state that you want to insert data into the column so that SQL server allows it.

Make sure you do not insert duplicate values for this column.

The best practice is to avoid inserting values into IDENTITY column.

Comment: what exactly I have to do to perform this operation?

Comment: just add this statement before your insert statement. I have updated my answer with what this statement does.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "[ID]"

write it like that:

INSERT INTO `your table name`

For example:
If you have Instructor table with attributes ID, name and dept_name
Use: Insert Command like bellow

```
Insert Into Instructor (ID, name, dept_name) Values (11111, 'Andrea', 'Biology');
```

Try this and let me show you result !!